# Why does the skew function require multiplying by n/((n-1)(n-2))?

Tags: skewness, degrees-of-freedom

The skew function as defined by [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SKEW-function-bdf49d86-b1ef-4804-a046-28eaea69c9fa) is as follows:

$$
\frac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)} \sum \left( \frac{x_i - \bar x}{s} \right)^3
$$

From Wikipedia, it's:

$$
\operatorname{E}\left[\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 \right]
$$

Where does the $\frac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ come from?

Comment: Probably to make the estimator unbiased.

Comment: to expand on @ŁukaszGrad's answer, because you have already estimated the mean (x\bar) and the variance x^2, so two parameters have already been measured, which means you have (n-2) left. You subtract n  for the mean, and then n-1 for the variance,

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly not *required*; if instead the (implied) factor of $\frac{n^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ was omitted, leaving $\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^3}{s^3} = m_3/s^3$ you'd have another widely-used sample skewness measure, $b_1$.

There's two potential reasons that factor may have been used.

1. It unbiases the sample third moment in the numerator. That is $E[m_3]=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n^2}\mu_3$. (See [here](http://modelingwithdata.org/pdfs/moments.pdf) for example)
2. It's a factor that converts $b_1=m_3/s^3$ -- the sample third central moment on the cube of the usual sample standard deviation -- to a related measure $G_1$, which is based on sample [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant)

   $$\hat{\gamma}_1=G_1 = k_3/k_2^{3/2}$$

   where $k_2$ and $k_3$ are unbiased estimators of the second and third cumulants. You sometimes see slightly different versions of $G_1$.

   See the discussion of $G_1$ in the Wikipedia article on [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness).